# Inverter EMI filter design

Tags: power-electronics, filter, inverter, emc

I'm designing an inverter with a switching frequency range of 10-40kHz. The inverter will run off of a DC power supply at a relatively low voltage (30-80VDC) and low power (~100W) for motor control applications.

I am currently working on the input EMI filter to attenuate common-mode and differential-mode noise. I will use DC link capacitors to reduce the differential-mode noise but after doing some research, have come across additional options:

- LC low-pass filter (differential-mode noise attenuation)
- Ferrite bead low-pass filter (differential-mode noise attenuation, specifically for high frequency noise)
- Common-mode choke (common-mode noise attenuation)

If I were to implement either of the low-pass filters, I plan on using a T configuration to match my low source and load impedances.

I have a couple questions about this design:

1. The application is not space or price constrained, so I don't see the harm in including all three options on top of the DC link caps. Is this a good plan?
2. Is a low-pass filter cutoff frequency of 100Hz a reasonable spot to attenuate the worst-case fundamental switching frequency of 10kHz?
3. How should I design around the resonance in a ferrite bead/LC low-pass filter? The inverter is for testing multiple motors, so I don't know the load impedance of the motor in advance and can't impedance match to that.

Comment: How much attenuation at the 10 KHz switching frequency do you need?  This is a key requirement.

Comment: It is hard to determine a number without having built the actual inverter, kind of a chicken and egg problem. Also, without knowing in advance the type or parameters of motor the inverter will test, a simulation won't be characteristic of the real life behavior. I guess what I can say is the more the better.

Comment: I agree, partially, about the load (motor) unknowns.  But with the proper modeling tools, you should be able to predict how much 10 KHz noise is coming back out of your inverter, once you have the inverter designed.

Comment: That's fair, and I should probably do a detailed simulation to decide on the low-pass cutoff in question 2. Do you have an opinion on questions 1 and 3?

Comment: Gonna have to think about those a bit.  I don't design input filters like that myself, but come across them during reviews with our power supply group.